# DNSSEC - Unable to sign the relevant files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, dnssec, authoritative

I have set up a working DNS server on an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS as part of a single server (DNS, SPF, Email, firewall etc)
IP: 192.168.122.189
Test Domain: jetj.ltd
Hostname:mail

The files I have are:
db.jetj.ltd:

```
;
; BIND data file for jetj.ltd  
;

$INCLUDE /etc/bind/keys/Kjetj.ltd.+008+12125.key

$TTL 86400

@       IN      SOA     mail.jetj.ltd. karti.jetj.ltd. (
                2023082501 ; Serial
                3600       ; Refresh
                1800       ; Retry
                604800     ; Expire
                86400      ; Minimum TTL
)
; Name Server (NS) records  
@       IN      NS      mail.jetj.ltd.
@       IN      A       192.168.122.189

; A record for the domain's nameserver
mail   IN      A       192.168.122.189

; Mail Exchanger (MX) record   
@       IN      MX      10 mail.jetj.ltd.
```

named.conf.options:

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    recursion yes;
    listen-on { 192.168.122.189; };
    allow-query { localhost; 192.168.122.0/24; }; // Allow queries from localhost and your local network
    forwarders {
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
    };
        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        dnssec-validation auto;
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};

trust-anchors {
    "." initial-key 256 3 8 "AwEAAagAIKlVZrpC6Ia7gEzahOR+9W29euxhJhVVLOyQbSEW0O8gcCjF
     FVQUTf6v58fLjwBd0YI0EzrAcQqBGCzh/RStIoO8g0NfnfL2MTJRkxoX
     bfDaUeVPQuYEhg37NZWAJQ9VnMVDxP/VHL496M/QZxkjf5/Efucp2gaD
     X6RS6CXpoY68LsvPVjR0ZSwzz1apAzvN9dlzEheX7ICJBBtuA6G3LQpz
     W5hOA2hzCTMjJPJ8LbqF6dsV6DoBQzgul0sGIcGOYl7OyQdXfZ57relS
     Qageu+ipAdTTJ25AsRTAoub8ONGcLmqrAmRLKBP1dfwhYB4N7knNnulq
     QxA+Uk1ihz0=";
};
```

named.conf.local:

```
zone "jetj.ltd" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.jetj.ltd";
    dnssec-policy default;
    inline-signing yes;
};

zone "122.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.192";
    dnssec-policy default;
    inline-signing yes;
};
```

When I run named-checkconf - no errors at all.
I get the key by running:

```
sudo dnssec-keygen -a RSASHA256 -b 2048 -f KSK -L 9000000 jetj.ltd
```

And I added these to the db.jetj.ltd file.

However when ever I try to dnssec-signzone I get the following errors:

```
karti@mail:/etc/bind$ dnssec-signzone -S -K keys/ db.jetj.ltd
dnssec-signzone: fatal: No signing keys specified or found.
```

I checked and changed key which looks like:

```
karti@mail:/etc/bind/keys$ cat Kjetj.ltd.+008+12125.key
; This is a key-signing key, keyid 12125, for jetj.ltd.
; Created: 20230905194204 (Tue Sep  5 19:42:04 2023)
; Publish: 20230905194204 (Tue Sep  5 19:42:04 2023)
; Activate: 20230905194204 (Tue Sep  5 19:42:04 2023)
jetj.ltd. 9000000 IN DNSKEY 257 3 8 AwEAAbSbc3FDpa6u5FWnxza3wBzY+j6/zj6fs/5UWzzC5EmVugKloM9H 2j+2y6K8ShWDj744COlOFA+JfbFHzhFWDeg/MpXyKX8ah5K2rB3apdQc 48BytgoXgflyBHO9/tHJOlkNDNiL7Nk3VBLABl2MZr2+XM5bQV9Bx8bA tBI+8+yPHMcq9hJ8ZZW8Fc2NENWw1cS+4hJpiNEM3vBVanRBKAfczZR5 Odx4qGoDBatDR00dfNzlrpr3cvy66giNEbDv2APPMO8YD6rTeT0GyMXM gQ1SULHxAo3G8GmzEiAd6rplKA4tZ+TXIPHZqx8/5Nu6moizXntxGOCU 4egalBQoQKs=
```

All help and comments appreciated. I have been on this for about a week with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

K

Comment: Are you sure you want to do the signing manually in the first place, instead of using BIND's existing automation? (And if so, why do you have 'inline-signing' enabled?)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I followed the instructions from the bind documentation and set up the automated service. In order for that to happen it had to have inline signing enabled. After this when I try the reverse zone it comes back with the ad flag. However I didn't get it with a forward zone search. I assume this is because it is not an authorised server. And to that I needed the files signed. If I forwarded my dns server to a root or Google server would it provide the ad flag and therefore not require my standalone server to be authorised?